# Get data's source in kettle

Tags: etl, kettle

When I use kettle , I was wandering how to get a table column's source column. Just for an example , after I have merged two tables into one table based on primary key already , Given any column in output table , I could judge whether table it belongs to and get the original column name in original table. Thank you for helping and sorry for my poor English...

https://i.stack.imgur.com/xoR0s.png

When I was given any field in table3 (suppose a field named A in table3) , I could know where it comes from without the graphical view (from java code or other ways) , like the original table name (here are input1 or input2) and the original column name(maybe B in input1 , but represents A in table3). Besides I use mysql.

Comment: Hi liu, Welcome to stackoverflow please post some sample data and code for better explanation

Comment: Thx for your attention :-)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are a couple of ways to do this:

1) Manually. If you right-click on the output step and choose Show Output fields (or whatever it's called), you will see the "origin step" for each of the outgoing fields. You can do the same for input fields. Then you can trace them back to those origin steps, and repeat the process of viewing the input fields at those steps, and seeing those fields' origins, and so on.  This is probably not what you're looking for.

2) With code. Prior to 6.0, you'd need to programmatically perform the same operations as are listed in option 1 above. In 6.0 there is the Data Lineage capability, which offers the [LineageClient API](https://github.com/pentaho/pentaho-metaverse/blob/master/core/src/main/java/org/pentaho/metaverse/client/LineageClient.java) that can find the origin fields for the specified output fields. For more information see my [blog post](http://funpdi.blogspot.com/2015/11/data-lineage-internals-in-pdi-60.html) describing the Data Lineage capability. Also I put a Gremlin Console in the PDI Marketplace, to make the use of LineageClient easier (and you can visually see the lineage graph too).